# Beating memcmp in C++

Tags: c++, performance

Once again I decided to beat system `memcmp` function. This time I decided to use a template and to "precompile" all cases from 0 to 31 bytes.

Result is 400% improvement - from about 1:15 min to 0:25 min.

Finally I had rewritten `memcmp_fixed_` with naive looking for statement and I noticed that the compiler can optimize it as well.

However I did not tested with random data, so I am not sure what role the cache line and branch predictor plays in the tests.

Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

namespace{

template<size_t SIZE>
int memcmp_fixed_(const unsigned char *s1, const unsigned char *s2){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        if (s1[i] != s2[i])
            return s1[i] - s2[i];

    return 0;
}

template<>
int memcmp_fixed_<1>(const unsigned char *s1, const unsigned char *s2){
    return *s1 - *s2;
}

template<size_t SIZE>
int memcmp_fixed_(const void *a1, const void *a2){
    const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char *) a1;
    const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char *) a2;

    return memcmp_fixed_<SIZE>(s1, s2);
}

}

inline int fast_memcmp(const void *a1, const void *a2, size_t const size){
    switch(size){
        case  0: return 0;

        case  1: return memcmp_fixed_< 1>(a1, a2);
        case  2: return memcmp_fixed_< 2>(a1, a2);
        case  3: return memcmp_fixed_< 3>(a1, a2);
        case  4: return memcmp_fixed_< 4>(a1, a2);
        case  5: return memcmp_fixed_< 5>(a1, a2);
        case  6: return memcmp_fixed_< 6>(a1, a2);
        case  7: return memcmp_fixed_< 7>(a1, a2);
        case  8: return memcmp_fixed_< 8>(a1, a2);
        case  9: return memcmp_fixed_< 9>(a1, a2);
        case 10: return memcmp_fixed_<10>(a1, a2);
        case 21: return memcmp_fixed_<21>(a1, a2);
        case 22: return memcmp_fixed_<22>(a1, a2);
        case 23: return memcmp_fixed_<23>(a1, a2);
        case 24: return memcmp_fixed_<24>(a1, a2);
        case 25: return memcmp_fixed_<25>(a1, a2);
        case 26: return memcmp_fixed_<26>(a1, a2);
        case 27: return memcmp_fixed_<27>(a1, a2);
        case 28: return memcmp_fixed_<28>(a1, a2);
        case 29: return memcmp_fixed_<29>(a1, a2);
        case 30: return memcmp_fixed_<30>(a1, a2);
        case 31: return memcmp_fixed_<31>(a1, a2);

        default: return memcmp(a1, a2, size);
    }
}

#include <cstdio>

#include <algorithm>    // min

size_t const MAX = 10000000000;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc != 3){
        printf("Usage:\n");
        printf("\t%s [string1] [string2]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    const char *s1 = argv[1];
    const char *s2 = argv[2];

    size_t const size1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t const size2 = strlen(s2);
    size_t const size  = std::min(size1, size2);

    volatile int x = 0;
    for(volatile size_t i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
        x += fast_memcmp(s1, s2, size);

    printf("%d %d\n", fast_memcmp(s1, s2, size), x );
}
```

And the baseline is this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

#include <cstdio>

#include <algorithm>    // min

size_t const MAX = 10000000000;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc != 3){
        printf("Usage:\n");
        printf("\t%s [string1] [string2]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    const char *s1 = argv[1];
    const char *s2 = argv[2];

    size_t const size1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t const size2 = strlen(s2);
    size_t const size  = std::min(size1, size2);

    volatile int x = 0;
    for(volatile size_t i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
        x += memcmp(s1, s2, size);

    printf("%d %d\n", memcmp(s1, s2, size), x );
}
```

Comment: How did you time your execution, to decide one was faster than the other?

Comment: Did not believe you when I first read it. So I timed it as well. I get `memcmp()` being approx. 15% faster when doing: `time ./a.out "Test String 1" "Test String 2"`. The whole point of `memcmp()` is that it is fast. Implementors of the standard libraries tune this for the platform they are building on specifically because of this and where possible use special machine code instructions designed specifically for this (They have access to features not available at the language level).

Comment: Not sure why you think implementing this as a loop will make it quicker. Especially since you are comparing a character at a time. You need to compare bigger object. Look up `Duff's device`.

Comment: @LokiAstari, Duff's device is way too evil to pull out :)

Comment: @LokiAstari, also I think on that scale performance difference is rather latency dependent (too small strings).

Comment: I use time for measure. I did several tests. For strings over say 8-10 bytes, standard function is indeed faster, but this can be avoided by deleting cases from the switch.

Comment: @Loki - thanks for Duffs device. My code expects the compiler to unroll the loops and or probably vectorize it. Not sure how the vectorization part can happen with branch inside the loop.

Comment: Why is `volatile` on `i` and `x`?

Comment: @Nick It will definitely unroll but because of the way it is organized it will still compare one byte at a time because it returns `s[2]-s[1]` on a byte scale. It would be faster if you compare ints and use Duffs device for the trailing couple of bytes. Unrolling integers comparing loops will produce more efficient code. I still don't think you will beat `memcmp()`

Comment: Did you compile both with `-O3`?

Comment: both -O3. comparing ints is difficult because of little endian. volatile to be sure optimizer not touch them.

Comment: Not sure how endian is relevant. You are not comparing integers you are comparing memory locations but you are doing it 4 bytes at a time. If you are not going to do that then you will never beat `memcmp()`.

Comment: memory location with 0x1122 will be seen as 0x2211 in little endian. So I can not really compare it. But say I can find if is different and let say re-scan same bytes again to find exact comparison.

Comment: @Nick. This is a standard optimization that will (probably) be done by the system `memcmp()` unless you are going to compare in larger chunks you are not going to be able to compete.

Comment: clang llvm memcmp implementation is very naive, but glibc doing something similar to that.

Comment: so the function works only on data less than 32 bytes? I don't think difference will be measurable, thus it is impossible to tell if it is faster. I'll need completely different benchmark then.

Comment: @MartinYork With big endian, comparing ints also compares the lexicographic order of the individual bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Since we're using the C++ wrappers around standard C functions (which is good - I like it!), we need namespace qualification of `std::size_t` and `std::memcmp`).  Although your implementation evidently takes advantage of the license to also include the unqualified names, it's not portable to rely on that.

Instead of repeating the type when casting `a1` to `s1` and `a2` to `s2`, we can just use `auto` (and let's be clear about the cast - prefer `reinterpret_cast` to a catch-all C-style cast).

I managed to simplify `memcmp_fixed_` by using a recursive template.  For me (with `g++ -03`), this gave roughly the same execution speed (I guess that loop unrolling makes the resultant binary very similar).  I got rid of the separate `void*` and `unsigned char*` overloads - that's just a compile-time overhead and makes no different to runtime speed, which gives 9 lines, compared to your 14 (counting physical lines that contain alphanumerics).

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
int memcmp_fixed_(const void *a1, const void *a2)
{
    auto const s1 = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(a1);
    auto const s2 = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(a2);
    auto const diff = *s1 - *s2;
    return diff ? diff : memcmp_fixed_<SIZE-1>(s1+1, s2+1);
}

template<>
int memcmp_fixed_<0>(const void*, const void*)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I slightly simplified the test program to make it a single-character change to build the baseline test (and to send error messages where they belong), and massively reducing the repeated code:

```
#if 1
#define test_memcmp fast_memcmp
#else
#define test_memcmp std::memcmp
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::fprintf(stderr, "Usage:\n\t%s [string1] [string2]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    const char *s1 = argv[1];
    const char *s2 = argv[2];
    auto const size  = std::min(strlen(s1), strlen(s2));

    volatile int x = 0;
    for (volatile std::size_t i = 0;  i < MAX;  ++i)
        x += test_memcmp(s1, s2, size);

    std::printf("%d %d\n", test_memcmp(s1, s2, size), x);
}
```

Comment: Or is `static_cast` more appropriate here - enlighten me if I'm wrong, please!

Comment: I would go with `static_cast` simply because it is the most common and the most difficult to mess up of the casting operators, but that's just a sane-defaults style thing. Otherwise, `reinterpret_cast` and `static_cast` are functionally identically here (this is evident from the fact that the standard defines the `reinterpret_cast`-behavior for pointer conversions as `static_cast` to `void*` followed by `static_cast` to new-pointer-type).

Comment: You did what?! You implemented memcmp with recursive templates and that _simplified_ the implementation?!

I recommend you take a look at the assembly that GCC and Clang produce from this. A lot of code... everything in unrolled. This is far from simple from the perspective of the compiler.

Comment: @MatthewM. agreed - I meant simplified for the author/reviewer!  And yes, we should probably find a value where we invoke `std::memcmp()` instead, to avoid creating huuuge instantiations.